# Error de permiso al abrir archivo DBF en conexión Microsoft JET de Integration Service SQL SERVER 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, ssis, ssms

muy buenos días comunidad, es mi primera pregunta publicada en esta hermosa comunidad.

Pero en resumen, estoy ejecutando un **workflow** mediante **SSIS de Visual Studio** el cual es un insert y update de un DBF (Archivo alojado en el servido interno de la empresa) hacia una tabla de SQL SERVER y se ejecuta perfecto en VS, lo despliego hacia **Integration Service Catalogs** en **SQL SERVER** (tambien
alojado en el servidor interno de la empresa) y al ejecutar el paquete en **SSMS** me aparece un error el cual es el siguiente.

> cargaDatosSCP:Error:Código de error SSIS DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. Error de OLE DB. Código de error: 0x80004005. Hay un registro OLE DB disponible. Origen: "Microsoft JET Database Engine" Resultado: 0x80004005 Descripción: "\\192.168.11.x\scp\SCP2\DAT" no es una ruta de acceso valida. Asegurese de que la ruta esta escrita correctamente y que esta conectado al servidor donde se encuentra el archivo.".

Se que es por falta de privilegios de acceso, pero no se a que usuario o servicio en el que se ejecuta hay que darlos, yo como usuario y el administrador del servidor Sql Server alojado tienen privilegios y accedemos al archivo, estuve viendo por varios foros y lo único que encontré fue que se le debe dar privilegios al objeto o usuario **IUSR** donde se los di pero tampoco funciona, no estoy muy claro de eso de **quien accede a esos archivo** cuando se ejecuta el **package.dtsx**.

Les agradecería infinito si es que me pudieran orientar con este problema, Saludos!

**[image: Microsoft SSMS]**

Comment: ¿Quién ejecuta el paquete? Si es un `job` de SQL Server puedes ver el usuario que lo ejecuta en las propiedades del mismo y asegurarte que tiene permisos

Comment: Aun no lo paso a Job, primero quiero validar si es que funciona para después pasarlo a Job, el error esta en cuando valido la tarea generada por SSIS en el Management Studio donde el SQL Server esta alojado en  (192.168.11.xx) donde la conexión **Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended properties=dbase 5.0** no puede acceder a la carpeta alojada en **\\192.168.11.zz\scp\SCP2\DAT\** por faltas de privilegios, entonces no se a quien debo darle esos privilegios.
Nota: Cabe destacar donde el esta alojado SQL SERVER tiene un dominio diferente al donde están los datos almacenados.